# Node.js Sequelize connection

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('abc', 'abc', 'abc', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mssql'
});
```

I am trying to connect the SQLServer from using above code, but getting below error 
on sequelize.authenticate()

```
Unable to connect to the database: { SequelizeConnectionError: Invalid arguments: "instanceName" must be a string
```

**Note: I am using the latest version of sequelize**

Comment: you are missing passing the port in options object.

Comment: right, I thought it will consider default port. Thanks Mohit

Comment: yes, either instance name or the port you will have to pass .

Answer (score 0):

Example of my connection

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
    operatorsAliases: Sequelize.Op.Aliases,
    freezeTableName: true,
    logging: console.log,
    dialect: 'mssql',
    host: 'host'
});
```